# Input default values not Displaying in Django through post method

Tags: javascript, python, html

i am working on project in which i have to used python to make blind person to access their account
so when they speak there name i want to display it on input field in forms using django[my view for register](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYaJd.png)

And beolow is my html code
in which i have used ajax to make post request to server

```
    <form action="" method="post" >

        <div class="form-group" align="center">

              <input type="text" name="Email" class="form-control"  value="{{ email }}" readonly placeholder="Email Id" id="myNumber" >
        </div>
          
           </br>

        <a type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg rounded-pill" href='{% url 'menu' %}' >Submit</a>
        </form>


  </div>
```

###### here i have used id to change default input value#######

    document.getElementById('myNumber').value = "{{ email }}";
 
###### here is the function to make post call #######

    function SendPostRequestHome(event){
        $.ajax({
        url: "{% url 'register' %}",
        method:"POST",
        data: { 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
        success: function (data) {

            if(data.result == 'success'){
                window.location = "{% url 'menu' %}";
            }
            else if(data.result == 'failure'){
                window.location = "{% url 'home' %}";
            }
        }
    });
    }

but when i run it work fine but it doesnt display anything on the input field
it take input and save it in email variable if print it shows it but not displaying in input field
plz answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning value to context dictionary on POST method so in GET method the dictionary is empty so you are sending None in your register view function to the input page. You should take care of the GET method and fill the values according to it.

Comment: yeah its works fine in get , as u say i have done putting dict inside the post call but then it shows local variable assignment before reference error because passing dict is in outside call so can you have help me how to do that it would be really helpfull for me plz

Comment: You should fill values from the model that contains email field.
It should be something like in your get method

email = MyEmailModel.objects.get(email=request.user.email)
dict={'email': email}